# Merging multiple PDFS's from one folder, and outputing merged pdf to another folder

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to merge multiple PDF's in the folder called 'Rate-Rule Attachments'

and output the merged file into 'Merged_PDF' folder using the following function

```
import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os
input_paths=os.walk('Rate-Rule Attachments')
output_path=os.walk('Merged_PDF')
def merger(output_path, input_paths):
    pdf_merger = PdfFileMerger()
    file_handles = []

    for path in input_paths:
        pdf_merger.append(path)

    with open(output_path, 'wb') as fileobj:
        pdf_merger.write(fileobj)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    paths = glob.glob('Rate-Rule Attachments\*')
    merger('VA.pdf', paths)
```

However, when I run the function I get the Superflous Whitespace Found in object header?

Is this a problem with the naming schemes? Or pdf itself?

Comment: According to https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/PyPDF2/pdf.py, that should not be a fatal error. Do you still get an output file?

Comment: Correct, I kept canceling the code when I saw it. But I did indeed get the correct output. Thank you Jussi.

Comment: You're welcome. I found that using `PdfFileMerger(strict=False)` is necessary to get many PDF files to read. I believe that it will also disable the warning message you got above.